# reading data from a file into array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question2_Arrays {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    double[]loanbalanceArray = new double[500];
    int index = 0;

    File file = new File("loanbalance.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    while(inputFile.hasNext()&& index<loanbalanceArray.length){
        loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
        index ++;
        }
    inputFile.close();
```

I am trying to read the contents of the text file loanbalance into an array sized 500 this is what i have so far but when i execute the program it gives me this error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)"

any suggestions where i could be going wrong?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html: you're reading an int, and the file contains something that can't be parsed as an int.

Comment: Even if I knew nothing about java I would read this text `InputMismatchException` and say well, it sounds like my input doesn't match what was expected. My code expects int from `inputFile.nextInt()` so I must not be giving an int. Then I check the input file. Did you do anything like this?

Comment: @takendarkk Who needs to read messages if you can ask other people to do the explaining for you ...

Comment: Also, why make your array of type `double` but then fill it with `int`?

Comment: sorry guys my mistake i put in nextint instead of nextDouble @takendarkk

Comment: but even when i change the hasnextInt to double it still gives me an error of type mismatch cannot convert boolean to double?@takendarkk

Comment: You checked if it has a next double, but did you change the part where you try to remove an int from the file?

Comment: this is what i have so far while(inputFile.hasNextDouble()|| index<loanbalanceArray.length){
   loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.hasNextDouble();
   index ++;
   }
@takendarkk

Comment: And you are sure you have doubles in your input file and they are separated correctly? Also, your while condition should be `&&`, not `||`. Think about what would happen if your file had 1000 numbers. Your while loop would run which is not good.

Comment: yes there are doubles in my input file and they are on a seperate line @takendarkk

Answer (score 0):

```
while (inputFile.hasNextDouble() || index<loanbalanceArray.length){
    loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.nextDouble();
    index ++;
    }
```

Use inputFile.hasNextInt method. 
Your input can return true on hasNext call but it can be not int or null and throw exception during call of `loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.nextDouble();`

And according to your comments you're using `loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.hasNextDouble()` for assignment, but you should use `loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.nextDouble()`

`hasNextDouble()` checking if your input has double value further and returns Boolean is so but `nextDouble()` returns actual next Double value of input

Comment: That could still throw `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: @takendarkk topicStarter just using loanbalanceArray[index] = inputFile.**hasNextDouble()** instead .nextDouble for assignment

Comment: i did that the error doesnt appear anymore but when i try to display the contents of the array it gives me weird characters rather than the contents of the file @Klever

Comment: @user3607224 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: the link just shows how to print string and int arrays. i want to learn how to print the contents of an array that is double. any other links if you have any would be useful @user3607224

Comment: @user3607224 same applicable for double.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

In your case:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(loanbalanceArray));